# Why rotation is not an observable?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, angular-momentum, rotation, observables

I am literally new to these terms, I read this somewhere that "some operators are not observables such as rotation" . Is the statement correct? Can't we measure or observe rotational properties of a system?

Edit: I am attaching a screenshot.

[image]

Also I am providing the link of the course.
https://www.coursera.org/learn/foundations-quantum-mechanics

Comment: I wonder if it is referring to spin.  Of course in a quantum particle, which is nothing but a wave in the quantum field, it is not possible to directly observe spin.  What is observed is angular momentum.

Answer (score 2):

An operator $A$ acting over a state $|\psi\rangle$ is an observable if $A=A^{\dagger}$ (it is its own self-adjoint or transpose conjugate).

What this means is that the eigenvalues of the operator are all real, and per the axioms of quantum mechanics, only the eigenvalues of observables are the possible to results of a measurement.

Given a rotation $R(\theta)$ over some axis and angle $\theta$, the rotation has to be unitary as it is a change of basis. This all means that $R(\theta)R^{\dagger}(\theta)=1$, but $R^{\dagger}(\theta)$ is not in general the matrix itself, it could be the rotation in the other direction $R^{\dagger}(\theta)=R(-\theta)$. So $R(\theta)$ is not Hermitian and not an observable.

On a more physical ground, (even classically) what would it mean to measure a rotation? You can measure a position or an angle, even the speed of rotation, but there is no clear value that we can associate to a rotation. A rotation is only an operator that modifies your state.